# How to join the ends of the bones in the character model?

Tags: rigging

I wanted to know how to join the bones for the spinal region. It is causing me a problem in moving further. Answers will be very valuable to me

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: in Edit mode you can select the top spine then shift the bottom spine, then Ctrl P (parent) > Keep Offset. But your setup is a bit unorthodox, you should switch the direction of the bottom spine, unless you have good reason not to

Comment: The base of one bone cannot connect to the base of another. In short, you should probably end up with the bottom of the spine being indirectly connected to the legs, so they float.